# How to understand RPN phrase in Faster-RCNN

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection

Sorry, it is all by one question but relate to many small questions. I can't split them into seperated questions.

1. For example, input picture size 960x640
2. Through VGG16 layer 13 Conv5_3, get feature_map 60x40x512
3. Do 3x3 convolution.

   3.1 How 3x3 convolution compress the output above to 1x512 ?

   3.2 I read some article said, RPN would random select 512 samples from 2000 anchors . If 1x512 matrix mean this  , what is 3x3 convolution doing ?
4. Loop feature_map, with 16 stride and 16 scale to find the center of the original map (corresponding feature map current point), cut 9 anchors out, calculate IoU< 0.3 as neg samples and IoU > 0.7 as pos samples.

   4.1 If there are several points on the feature_map, how to cover the GT? I mean, because it need IoU > 0.7 to label pos sample, here IoU refers to [ the intersection of the area(map from this point to the original image) and  GT], or [all the area of GT]? I think it should be the former.
5. After all the loops are over, filter out the positive and negative samples by nms . Is it possible to have multiple anchors in a single point, or is nms sure to filter this out?
6. Pass to softmax.

   6.1 My problem is , in many cases,  the positions(labeled by positive and negative) of the points on the feature_map  are different. Because the position of the parameter is also fixed at a specific position on the feature_map, how to find proposals from an image in the detect phase?

   6.2 random selection of anchors is at here? ? ?
7. RoI merges feature_map and proposals to do pooling. (1. roi (roi said a group of anchors it) is located in the feature map , and get the patch zone in feature map 2. something like SPP layer(7x7 down sampling ) is applied to the feature map patch, transform to fixed size of features, to fit full connection layer)
8. Another softmax. (Training phase using BP to tune the parameters), my problem is that in many cases the positions of the points on the feature_map each time labeled positive and negative are different. Because the position of the parameter is also fixed at a specific position on the feature_map, how to find proposals from the image in the detect phase?
9. RoI compare to GT, do reggession.

After finishing the above questions, re-think again. I found my understanding of anchors, proposals a bit confusing. Does many anchors compose to a proposal?
If so, then the above 6 becomes

6. Select 512 anchors , pass their parameters into softmax, the output show if it is part of the target object. So this layer is the detect phase. When doing detect phase, just loop all the anchors to get the possible ones .

   6.1 But in this case, how RPN output bbox size (x, y, w h) ? I think it need merge selected anchors and then scale to the size of the original image , to get the bbox size.

   6.2 If operation is merger , then randomly selected 512 from 2000 is likely to miss some areas, isn't it ?

Mainly is 3 and 6, and I think all of them are highly relative can not be seperated. Some are just need yes or no confirm, thanks

Comment: There are too many questions here, you should split it into multiple questions that *can* be answered.

Comment: @Matias Valdenegro They are all related. Once I seperated one without others, lost the meaning .  Some question can be answared by just by Yes or No because I just want a confirm . I just show all to let people know what I don't know. If they choose a point to answer, I can pick the hilight the question and accept answer, then post left ones to another question. Because it is really hard to seperate.